# AttributeError: module 'importlib.machinery' has no attribute 'BuiltinImporter' when creating venv

Tags: python-3.x, python-venv

When I try to create a virtual env with `python3` (`python3 -m venv <ENV_NAME>`), I get the following error:

```
python3.7 -m venv watcher                                                                                  hossein@hostMHY12
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<USER_NAME>/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 15, in <module>
    import importlib.util
  File "/Users/<USER_NAME>/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/util.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import abc
  File "/Users/<USER_NAME>/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/abc.py", line 83, in <module>
    _register(MetaPathFinder, machinery.BuiltinImporter, machinery.FrozenImporter,
AttributeError: module 'importlib.machinery' has no attribute 'BuiltinImporter'
```

This is a strange error, and I couldn't find any answers online. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue in my case was some sort of conflict with my `miniconda`. Once I removed it as explained in [this link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-completely-remove-Miniconda-from-a-Mac-OS-X-I-guess-its-messing-up-my-system-I-probably-did-something-wrong-during-the-first-build-install), everything was fine.